# G Sheet - Sumifs for data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a sheet with bank statements and a want to set up a summary sheet with the total amounts per client.

I know how to do that from within the statements sheet, e.g. summing up client A:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B,A1:A,"A")
```

[image]

But how can I do it directly from the summary sheet? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I do it directly from the summary sheet?

Your summary sheet is just **another tab**

```
=SUMIF('summary sheet'!A31:B41,"A",'summary sheet'!B31:B41)
```

Your summary sheet is a **different spreadsheet altogether**
Neither `SUMIF` nor `SUMIFS` work well when referring to a different spreadsheet.

In this case you should use a combination of the **[`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)** function and the **[`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)**

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","'summary sheet'!A31:B41"),"select Sum(Col2) where Col1='A' LABEL Sum(Col2) '' ")
```

*(please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.
I should have mentioned that it is another tab

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you for taking the time to accept.